# Removing all Rangy formatting from a selection

Tags: rangy

After applying several styles with Rangy to a selection the HTML goes to

```
<span class="bold  font18 italic"> sample text</span>
```

Now I'd like a button that removes all the formatting I've added to that selection, but I'm not seeing any simple way to do that.  I could use `.isAppliedToSelection()` to run through all the possible classes I could have added, but when you count all the possible font sizes, colors, font-families, font-styles, etc., that I could have assigned, that's a huge number to go through, and doesn't seem like the right thing to do.  The Rangy `isAppliedToSelection()` must be reading the styles applied to the selection so it seems that it could just tell us what classes are there, instead of making us guess.   Is there any way to make it do that?

Thanks